# Map complex shape onto $w=iz^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

So I'm given a little pizza-slice region with bounds $|z|\leq 2$ and $0\leq y \leq x$

I've already converted this to $r\leq2$ and $0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$

Now, I'm asked to sketch the image of R under the mapping $w=iz^2$ and explain.

I've never really understood mapping. Would someone be able to give me a walkthrough on this?

I tried looking at $w=iz^2$ so $|w| = i|z|^2$ and from there we get $|z|=\pm\sqrt{\frac{|w|}{i}}$

Then I see that $\pm\sqrt{\frac{|w|}{i}}\leq 2$ so $\sqrt{\frac{|w|}{i}}\leq 2$ and $-\sqrt{\frac{|w|}{i}}\leq2$ Which gets me $|w|\leq4i$ and $|w|\geq4i$ and if $w=u+iv$ then $4i\leq\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\leq4i$ so $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}=4i$ so $u^2+v^2=-16$ but honestly I feel like this is wrong and I have no idea where to go from here even if it's right.

Comment: I think $\theta\le\frac{\pi}4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
R=\{z=re^{i\theta}\;:\;0\le r\le 2, 0\le\theta\le\pi/4\}
$$
and writing $i=e^{i\pi/2}$
then calling $\phi(z):=iz^2$, we want to describe $\phi(R)$.

Now if $z\in R$,
$$
\phi(z)=\phi(re^{i\theta})=ir^2e^{i2\theta}=r^2e^{i(2\theta+\pi/2)}
$$
so, $0\le r \le 2$ clearly implies $0\le r^2\le 4$ and $0\le\theta\le\pi/4$ implies $\pi/2\le2\theta+\pi/2\le\pi$. Now (since these last transformations are bijections in the given domains and codomains) you get that
$$
\phi(R)=\{w=se^{i\varphi}\;:\; 0\le s\le4,\;\pi/2\le\varphi\le\pi\}
$$
which is a bigger slice (twice the angle and $90°$ rotated) of a bigger pizza (twice the radius).

Comment: How do you know $z=re^{i\theta}$?

Comment: Every complex number can be written in such a way. It is called polar form.

Comment: Is $ie^{2\theta}=e^{2\theta+\pi/2}$ just another property that I should know?

Comment: yes, once you rewrite $i$ the way i did